# How to encrypt and decypt data in table MariaDB using PHP, AES 128 bit?

Tags: php, encryption, aes

I have a table that I want to encrypt and decrypt with PHP AES ECB 128 bit. I have an AES code from my lecturer. This is the file https://pastebin.com/7rFVpxr0

How to use encrypt function so I can encrypt data from MariaDB?

Here is my code for encryption:

```
session_start();
include 'koneksi.php';
require 'AES.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_pelanggan";
$query = mysqli_query($koneksi, $sql);

while($database = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $no = $database["no"];
    $nama =encrypt($database["mama"], "QWERTYUIUYTREWQW");
    $senin = $database["senin"];
    $selasa = $database["selasa"];
    $rabu = $database["rabu"];
    $kamis = $database["kamis"];
    $jumat = $database["jumat"];
    $total = $database["total"];

    echo "<tr>
        <td>$no </td>
        <td>$nama</td>
        <td>$senin </td>
        <td> $selasa </td>
        <td> $rabu </td>
        <td> $kamis</td>
        <td> $jumat </td>
        <td> $total</td>
    </tr>";
}
```

It reproduce error:

> Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function AES::encrypt()

I already try to find a solution, using `mcrypt`, but it is not supported again in PHP 7, other solution support just text not field in table. Using SQL `AES_ENCRYPT()` but it only work for 1 cell, not a field.

Comment: `QWERTYUIUYTREWQW` is this actually a constant? what php version are you using?

Comment: sorry, my false. I already edited it. It is a string. PHP 7.2.7

Comment: If you have to use the AES encryption/decryption function from the AES class provided with the pastebin-link I miss the initialisation of the class. Secondly this class is encrypting only plaintext of exact 16 bytes length - shorter or longer longer plintext will raise an error. If you do NOT have to use this AES class I recommend PHP with openssl.

Comment: $AES = new AES();is it not the initialisation? @Michael

Answer (score 0):

You are using an external library "AES.php" for the crypto work but I do not see that
it is initialized AND You're working with an instance.

Below you find a complete working example BUT beware - **I'm using not the AES-class you provided in the pastelink**. The library I'm using seem to come from the same author and has the same version number but it works with this lib. If you should need a docfile there is one here: https://github.com/axquired24/hiweb/blob/master/AES/AES-docs-en.html beneath the AES.class.php I'm using for my example. Just place the lib to folder of you're choice and adjust the path.

Second advise: this class is using the **unsecure AES ECB mode** - do not use this in production!

Third advise: my example has a fixed keylength of 16 byte (here represented in hex notation) - it has to been exact 16 byte length!

Fourth advise: the AES.class.php is been able to encrypt and decrypt plaintext with a maximum length of 16 characters - **longer plaintexts will be cut off**!

As I'm not a specialist in database-programming my example just covers the encryption and decryption part.

This is the result:

```
plaintext(hex): 416c6963652068617320612063617400
cryptext (hex): 4f96c7d275b03645fc51a4870d23556c
decrypttext (hex): 416c6963652068617320612063617400
decrypttext: Alice has a cat

second example with plaintext longer then 16 chars
plaintext(hex): 416c69636520686173206120626c61636b20636174
cryptext (hex): 86e1d636342360577ed63b03b2af4239
decrypttext (hex): 416c69636520686173206120626c6163
decrypttext: Alice has a blac
```

That's the code of my testing class:

```
<?php
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62749785/how-to-encrypt-and-decypt-data-in-table-mariadb-using-aes-php-128-bit#comment110994731_62749785
require_once('New\AES.class.php');
$Cipher = new AES();
$key_128bit = '2b7e151628aed2a6abf7158809cf4f3c';

$plaintext = $Cipher->stringToHex('Alice has a cat');
print 'plaintext(hex): ' . $plaintext . PHP_EOL . '<br>';
// Encryption
$cryptext = $Cipher->encrypt($plaintext, $key_128bit);
print 'cryptext (hex): ' . $cryptext . PHP_EOL . '<br>';
// Decryption
$decrypttext = $Cipher->decrypt($cryptext, $key_128bit);
print 'decrypttext (hex): ' . $decrypttext . PHP_EOL . '<br>';
print 'decrypttext: ' . $Cipher->hexToString($decrypttext) . PHP_EOL . '<br>';

// second example with plaintext longer then 16 chars
print PHP_EOL . '<br>' . 'second example with plaintext longer then 16 chars' . PHP_EOL . '<br>';
$plaintext = $Cipher->stringToHex('Alice has a black cat');
print 'plaintext(hex): ' . $plaintext . PHP_EOL . '<br>';
// Encryption
$cryptext = $Cipher->encrypt($plaintext, $key_128bit);
print 'cryptext (hex): ' . $cryptext . PHP_EOL . '<br>';
// Decryption
$decrypttext = $Cipher->decrypt($cryptext, $key_128bit);
print 'decrypttext (hex): ' . $decrypttext . PHP_EOL . '<br>';
print 'decrypttext: ' . $Cipher->hexToString($decrypttext);
?>
```

Last but not least - the code of the AES.php class is available here (as it is too long I'm not been able to provide it here) - get it with this link: https://github.com/axquired24/hiweb/blob/master/AES/AES.class.php.